# Sorting v-data-table checks checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is anyone able to determine why sorting this table will automatically check some boxes? And how the boxes can be checked when their value is not in the "checked" array?

```html
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <div>
            <v-data-table
                show-select
                :headers="headers"
                :items="desserts"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
                <template v-slot:items="props">
                    <td><v-checkbox v-model="checked" :value="props.item.name" /></td></td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/EoghanCurtin/pen/ExPYqpY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weirdness is related to a few overlapping invalid values:

- you're using the same `v-model` for all checkboxes
- you're using a `string` instead of `boolean` as `v-model` for checkboxes. It's actually an array of strings before you sort for the first time and then it becomes string (because of `:value` attribute on `<v-checkbox>`, pointing at a string).
  Test with `<pre>{{checked}}</pre>` in your codepen.
- you're closing the first `<td>` twice (invalid html).

A possible fix:

```
<template v-slot:items="{ item }">
  <td><v-checkbox v-model="cb[item.name]" /></td>
  <td v-text="item.name" />
  <td class="text-xs-right" v-text="item.calories" />
</template>
```

...

```
data: () => ({
  cb: {},
  ...
}),
computed: {
  checked() {
    return Object.entries(this.cb)
      .filter(o => o[1]).map(o => o[0])
    }
},
...
```

See it working [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/yLeLBRe).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However notice on loading if you sort the table by calories before checking any boxes, some boxes will be checked.

Comment: I updated the example. Also added a nice computed which gives you the selection in array form. The actual problems were ***a)*** invalid value for checkbox `v-model` (string instead of boolean) and ***b)*** invalid html (you're closing first `<td>` twice). Once those are fixed it starts working as intended.

Comment: @tao, Thanks for the help. I'm having the same issue. I looked at your codepen and the show-select header "check all" checkbox is missing there.  When I model my code after yours, the sorting and retaining correct checkboxes works, but the "check all" stops working.  Any tips?

Comment: I'd argue the codepen is not missing anything. It answered the question being asked, which didn't contain any "check all". Since you have a "check all" you have a different question. Please ask it separately and create a *runnable* [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

If you want your checkboxes to follow their corresponding item when sorting - then you will have to change their definition like this

```
<v-checkbox 
  :value="checked.includes(props.item.name)" 
  @change="toggleCheckbox(props.item.name)" 
/>
```

and then use the following function to toggle the on/off state

```js
    toggleCheckbox(item)
    {
      const idx = this.checked.indexOf(item);
      if(idx === -1) this.checked.push(item);
      else this.checked.splice(idx,1);
    }
```

---

When the data-table sorts its items - it does not sort your checkboxes. So your checkboxes' value is being changed dynamically (because corresponding `item.name` is different after sorting).

If you need no more than 1 checkbox per row - it is better to utilize the [built-in checking support](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#selectable-rows) for data-tables

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the sorting of the check boxes. However I am fairly confident the sort function acts on the entire row. The bigger mystery is how we go from no checked boxes to 2 checked boxes if you load the codePen and click calories before doing anything else.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much for that. I will accept this answer even though I still don't understand why this work-around is necessary. In your opinion is this a bug, expected behavior or me trying to hard to make a component do something it want built for?

Comment: You will have to look inside the Vuetify source code for this - there are `value`, `internalValue`, `lazyValue`, `isActive`, `isDirty`. Perhaps when the `value` changes dynamically it leads to some discrepancy with the other internal fields of `<v-checkbox>`